# Playwright Python: How to locate an iframe object that has a dynamic ip and no name/url?

Tags: python, playwright, webautomation, playwright-python

I'm trying to click a button within an iframe that has a dynamically generated id. This is the HTML of it:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="Container.aspx?type=topgen&amp;menu_id=6088&amp;activityStepId=2-1&amp;MIR002AC;006087&amp;client=S3" class="" style="overflow:auto;width:100%;height:100%;" id="ext-gen1313"></iframe>
```

The id is usually a "ext-gen" + 4 numbers. The frame always contains MIROO2AC word within *src*, so I thought it would be possible to locate the frame with that.

Problem is, when I do page.frames I see no such frame. I have a feeling that it is somehow not loaded.

So, two questions:

1. How to find a frame based on *src* text?
2. How to ensure that all frames are loaded?

So far I have tried to locate it through name, but there is no name in it, and the id's are dynamically changing, so also not really possible.

Doing page.frames does not retrieve that particular one.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the only way to get a Frame is with a name or url (looking at `.frame()`, and I assume `.frames` is looking for a name). You could try accessing the specific frame with [`.frame()` and the url regex option](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-frame) to just capture that string you said should always be there.

Either way, it looks like you just said you needed to click a button within the frame, so you could just use [`.frame_locator()`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-frame-locator) to locate and pass through the frame to locate elements within. With that, you could take advantage of [css attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to use partial values from the id or src attributes. So something like this:

```py
page.frame_locator(‘[id^=“ext-gen”]’).locator(buttonLocator).click();
```